# Can I omit "og:url" when using link rel="canonical"

Tags: html, seo, metadata, share-open-graph

When setting up a new webpage and to prevent duplicate content issues on search engines, I am using the canonical tag `<link rel="canonical" href="https://example.com/slug" />`.

I came across of the [open graph protocol](https://ogp.me/) to improve the experience when sharing the webpage on social media.

In my case I am planning to use canonical to eliminate duplicates between http/https, non-www/www or remove url parameters such as `https://example.com/slug?foo=bar`.

For this case, it looks like the canonical tag and the open graph metadata `og:url` would do the same function. Should I include both or could I safely omit the `og:url` metadata?

Thank you in advance

Comment: I voted to close this question because general SEO questions are off-topic. Only programming-related SEO questions are acceptable on Stack Overflow. Non-programming SEO questions should be asked on [webmasters.se].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should **use both**! The reason is that `og:url` is only used by social media bots (Facebook, Twitter, LinkedIn), but search engine bots like Google bot will look for `rel="canonical"` when indexing your content.